# "Marca d'água" com CSS

Tags: html, css

#### Cenário teste

Tenho um input em um `<td>`, em que o fundo do `<td>` tem cor:

```css
td {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="marcado">
      <input type="number"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

#### Dúvida

- Gostaria de saber, como posso criar uma "marca d'água" com o *CSS* nesse fundo do `<td>`, para que eu possa utilizá-lo incluindo pela *class* (no exemplo, classe "marcado").

---

#### Exemplo de possíveis resultados esperados

[image: prospecto]

Comment: Tem coisas que é melhor com imagens, eu sei que tem as dicas com CSS puro, mas tem coisas que se for falar dos problemas ou da complexidade daria duas páginas de texto, então vou me limitar a isso, background-image e SVG casariam bem para resolver o seu caso ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo, é 100% com CSS e tudo feito com `background`, repare que mesmo se um input for maior o canto não deforma. E vc pode controlar facilmente o tamanho da marca pelo `background-size`

```css
.marcado {
  padding: 2em;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, red 50%, red 55%, transparent 55%, transparent 60%, red 60%), 
  linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
    /*controla o tamanho do chanfro vermelho aqui*/
  background-size: 40px 40px, 100% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="marcado">
      <input type="number"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="marcado">
      <input type="number" style="width: 400px;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso com HTML e CSS utilizando o elemento before
E então utilizar uma classe como "-active" para mostrar ou esconder o mesmo

```css
table td {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #ff0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden
}

table td:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="marcado">
      <input type="number"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cara uma dica, não precisa publicar 2 resposta, apenas edite a outra antiga e inclua o snippet do código nela

Comment: Primerira vez respondendo aqui heheheh
Valeu amigo

Comment: Já fica a dica rss

Comment: Willyan, mas se eu fizer dessa forma, todas ficaram com a marca, não é? você adicionou direto no `td`, eu queria que fosse uma classe, assim eu adiciono só em alguns...